# After checking out Subversion code into Eclipse, how do I get it to build?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

This problem has been frustrating me for some time...

A lot of sites like Sourceforge use SVN or Subversion to manage their code. I have little problem compiling SVN code in C++, but when it comes to Java, my IDE gives me a headache.

I've installed Subclipse for SVN support for Eclipse, and it works. I can check out any code into my Workspace. Now Subclipse will put the whole thing into a special project of some sort that can't be compiled. So I search Google for something and I come up with modifying the eclipse XML file to specify the 'nature' to be a Java project.

Okay, now it's a Java project. Say I have a folder structure like:

```
\src
\data
\graphics
```

I get 800 compiler errors complaining the package name is `org.company.SomePackage` instead of `src.org.company.SomePackage`.

Then what I do is create *packages* called src, data, graphics, etc, instead of just folders. I cut and paste everything in the folders into the packages and *finally* I can compile it.

What is a better way to do this?

EDIT: I can only check out anything SVN as a SVN project, and there's no way within Eclipse to change that to a Java project. How can I check out the SVN as a java project in  the first place?

Answer (score 4):

> I get 800 compiler errors complaining
>   the package name is
>   org.company.SomePackage instead of
>   src.org.company.SomePackage.

Right click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source Tab -> Add "src" as a source folder and remove any others.

Answer (score 0):

it thinks your source is stored in root folder.  you need to specify to the project that /src is the source folder.

Answer (score 0):

In general when we have an Eclipse project, which contains Java code – but we didn’t set it up as a Java project when we created or checked out this project, we are struck. And Eclipse doesn’t allow to change the project type inside the Gui. So we need to add the java nature as below.
1.  Close your project.
2.  Open your project file (which is located in your root directory of the appropriate project) called .project with your default editor. Search for

```
< natures>
< /natures>
```

and change it to as below

```
< natures>
<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
< /natures>
```

Save the changed file.
3.  Open the project again – now it should become a java project.

Then do the following as explained by Kevin
On the Project Explorer Window ->Right click on the specific Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source Tab -> Add "src" as a source folder and remove any others.
For me when I went into “Source Tab” – the “src” folder was already added, but it was not giving me the desired result (ie I was still not seeing the .java files in the project explorer window). So I removed the “src” filed that was already added in the Source Tab and then added them again. And then all worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure proper source paths.  Some open source projects make this automatic by checking their .project and .classpath files in with the rest of their files.  For others, you'll have exactly the problem you are having.  You need to set the classpath so the Java compiler knows where to find the source.  You right click on the project and select properties and configure an arbitrary classpath, but the answer given by Kevin is easier for a beginner.