# taking previous java code from Tortoisesvn

Tags: java, eclipse, tortoisesvn

I am working on TortoiseSVN and need help with an issue. The current code I am working on has been changed, but I need to review the code (go through the code) that was previously worked on. The previous code is also present on the svn location. I need to know how I can look at that code in the eclipse IDE. That is, I want to view the previous java code along with the new one in eclipse and compare them. I have installed svn into eclipse from the following link: 
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

kindly help...

Comment: It is discussed a bit while ago in stackoverflow, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589021/after-checking-out-subversion-code-into-eclipse-how-do-i-get-it-to-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Shiam Shabbir Himel and Estragon, but actually i wanted to look at the previous code, i mean the code which was some time back and of which i did not had the checkout. Though i found the answer: you need to install SVN in your eclipse from the link: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x.  After the SVN is installed, you need to have imported the latest code in eclipse, then right-click on the code window and select: Compare with>> Revision. This will get you all the revision history and you just have to select the version that you have to compare with. It will show you two screens with clear comparison between them. Thats the way it is!!

Answer (score 0):

try to make a repository into your local drive. then download your svn files using svn checkout into that repository folder.your previous code must be there in the repository folder. then open a new project in eclipse using existing source option and locate your local repository>your project folder. this will open a new project consisting with your previous code.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a svn project in eclipse you have a chance to specify which revision you want to import (by default, head revision)